# Open port 5672/tcp for access to RabbitMQ on Mac

Tags: mac, networking, port

I have RabbitMQ in its latest version installed on my Mac with default configuration and when I'm accessing it from localhost there's no issue what so ever. But today I build a linux machine on local network and no way I'm able to connect to my RabbitMQ server remotely from that machine. I shut down all the firewalls on my Mac and everything that could possibly block the connection. I'm perfectly able to connect to MongoDB running on different port and to any other application, ssh to my macbook and so on, but I can't connect to RabbitMQ (even when I change the port its running on). When I run `nmap` on linux to check if the appropriate port is open on my Mac I get this:

```
>> nmap -p 5672 192.168.1.101 
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.101
Host is up (0.00019s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5672/tcp closed amqp
```

But when I do the same thing right on my Mac:

```
>> nmap -p 5672 localhost
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00049s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
5672/tcp open  amqp
```

I added rule to `ipfw` manually and added `rabbitmq-server` to `system preferences -> security -> firewall -> advanced` applications list to allow all incoming connections just in case, but it didn't help. Any idea how to force the port to be open for network access from another computer in local network? When I do it the other way around (install rabbitmq on linux and connect to it from mac) it runs fine..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When I installed RabbitMQ on Mac OS X, via brew, I had the same problem with port 5672 only being open on localhost.

It turned out that the file `/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` contained an entry for `NODE_IP_ADDRESS` to bind it only to localhost. Removing the `NODE_IP_ADDRESS` entry from the config binds the port to [all network inferfaces](http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html).

Answer (score 5):

It seems the daemon is binding 127.0.0.1 instead 0.0.0.0, you can check it using netstat tool

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was a combination of both of the  prior answers.

Make your `/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` looks like this:

```
#rabbitmq-env.conf
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq
NODE_IP_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
NODENAME=rabbit@localhost
```

If I remove the `NODE_IP_ADDRESS` entry completely, rabbitmq gives me errors.

Answer (score 0):

what account are you using to connect to the RabbitMQ. If you are using guest account. This might help

https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Comment: SU's purpose is to build a knowledgebase rather than a collection of links to answers elsewhere.  External links can break, in which case your answer would have no value.  Please include the essential information in your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading..